# $watch is not working with arrays

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am watching and array if it changes then i want to call a function

```
$scope.$watch(
            $scope.aQuestions,
            function fncheckQuesCount(newValue, oldValue) {
                debugger;
                if (newValue === oldValue) {
                    return;
                } 
                else fnGetQues();
            });
```

here $scope.aQuestions is an array

but when i m running this ,it is showing newValue and oldValue as undefined.

Comment: try replacing `});` with `}, true);` (Or use `$watchGroup`)

Answer (score 4):

Should be

```
$scope.$watch("aQuestions",
```

Or

```
$scope.$watch(function (){
        return $scope.aQuestions;
},
```

This is because angular needs a way of repeatedly checking what the value is.

In your version you just pass in the value of the array (undefined). When the value changes angular doesn't know,  because it has no reference to the array.

Comment: As an addition, consider using `$watchCollection`